# Inject entityManager into custom Hibernate Interceptor class

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, interceptor

I want to inject the entityManager from Hibernate on an Hibernate Interceptor Class. I'm using EJBs and JBoss. The transaction is JTA and the provider is the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.

I tried to do it like that:

```
@Stateless(name = "HistoricInterceptor")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class HistoricInterceptorImpl extends EmptyInterceptor implements HistoricInterceptor {

@PersistenceContext(name = "windi")
private EntityManager em;

// overriden methods, etc

}
```

But the reference to entityManager is always null.

Is this behaviour expected? How can I access an entityManager from within an Interceptor class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had given up on that exact solution. Instead, I've created another class that has the EJB Annotations. The interceptor will call that EJB by using a provider class that lookup up EJB classes on the context of the application. There, the entityManager is correctly associated.